# All derivations are directional derivatives

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, manifolds

Let $X : C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a derivation, so i.e. linear and satisfying the Leibniz Rule 
$$X(fg)=X(f) \cdot  g(a)+X(g) \cdot f(a)$$
for some fixed $a \in \mathbb{R}^n.$ Then I would like to see that $X = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}|_a.$ So I want to see that $X$ is essentially a directional derivative.

Comment: Here, ℂ∞(ℝn) is all continuous derivatives of all orders??

Comment: @J.G yes, I adjusted the notation a little bit.

Comment: I'm not sure of your question here. You want us to solve the function with X=other operation?

Comment: @J.G. I want you to show this or give me a suitable hint :-)

Comment: Expand in Taylor series and use the fundamental theorem of calculus. You just need this.

Comment: @user40276 not every smooth function has a taylor series.

Comment: Every smooth function have a Taylor series with an integral remainder. You have to use this.

Comment: @RealAnalysis: Hi RealAnalysis. Is there something wrong with my solution below? Just wanted to ask as you haven’t mentioned anything about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As user40276 has mentioned, using Taylor’s Theorem, we can write
$$
\forall \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}: \quad
f(\mathbf{x}) =
f(\mathbf{a}) + \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}
                                 \Bigg|_{\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{a}} \cdot
                                 (x_{i} - a_{i}) + R(\mathbf{x}),
$$
where $ R: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R} $ is a linear combination of **products** of smooth functions that vanish at $ \mathbf{a} $.

Hence, if $ \Theta_{i} $ denotes the map $ \mathbf{x} \mapsto x_{i} - a_{i} $, then by the linearity of $ X $, the Leibniz Rule and also the fact that $ X $ sends constant functions to $ 0 $, we obtain
$$
\forall f \in {C^{\infty}}(\mathbb{R}^{n}): \quad
X(f) =
\sum_{i = 1}^{n} X(\Theta_{i}) \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}
                                     \Bigg|_{\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{a}}.
$$